# $scope variable with checkbox inconsistency

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling with some `$scope` variables in my angularjs-app.

I want to visualize 'Modules' that have serveral 'Channels' and those channels can be hidden/visible. I want to hide channels in a channel-popup by double-clicking on that channel.

angular-Controller snippet:

```
$scope.dblclick = function(chid) {
    $scope.chclicked = chid;
    $scope.hidden = $scope.moduledata.channels[chid].hidden !== 0 ? true : false;
    $scope.popupvisible = true;
};

$scope.popupok = function() {
    $scope.moduledata.channels[$scope.chclicked].hidden = $scope.hidden === true ? 1 : 0;
    $scope.popupvisible = false;
};

$scope.popupcancel = function() {
    $scope.popupvisible = false;
};

$scope.closePopup = function() {
    $scope.popupvisible = false;
};
```

Before showing the popup, I set (I try to) the current `'hidden'` value and `channel-id` to have access to them when closing the popup.

The checkbox in the popup has `ng-model="hidden"` set.

The problem now is that the hidden values in the `moduledata` doesn't get updated/changed and `$scope.hidden` always keeps the last value of the checkbox in popup - for all channels.

The `$scope.chclicked` works fine though.

I made a [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/yPOJ4tMo5M9BRO9acqQh?p=preview) to visualize my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [the following Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L8hdVmB7x8nvLVOjFmr3?p=preview) based on your one.

[`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) created a new scope, that's the reason why you can't just use `hidden` in the `ng-model` in the popup template.

You need:

```
ng-model="moduledata.channels[chclicked].hidden"
```

**Edit 1**

`popup` object has been created to store all information related to the popup including `hidden` variable.

```
$scope.popup = {
  visible: false,
  url: 'channeleditpopup.html',
  hidden: false
};
```

Next, in the popup template:

```
ng-model="popup.hidden"
```

In the `popupok` function:

```
$scope.moduledata.channels[$scope.chclicked].hidden = $scope.popup.hidden ? 1 : 0;
```

In the `dblclick` function:

```
$scope.popup.hidden = false;
```

Comment: @Appeiron It's said in the [Angular JS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) that this directive creates new scope and executes at priority level 400.

Comment: Ok, that would work. But now it hides/unhides my channel immediately. I want to apply changes only when 'ok' is clicked